# Spring batch reading CSV file move data to java data structure

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

i can see spring batch examples, read CSV file and write into DB, read XML file and write into CSV etc.
Here my requirement is Read CSV file using Spring Batch and move the CSV file data into Java Collections data structure, later let me take decision what do next, 

 Is there any way to Spring batch read file( CSV, XML etc) and move data to collections data structure (List, Set etc) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what the item writer interface does - https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemWriter.html

It gives you a list of items that were processed in a chunk. You can then do whatever you want with this list.

All you need to do is create a class that implements the ItemWriter interface and you should be good to go